# how to wait for angular2 http request data async

Tags: angular, asynchronous, rxjs, angular2-services, angular-http

I have three component, one service.
Three component depends on a public data, which is get from remote server by angular/http (or httpClient module in angular4) module.
The public data, let me define it as **DATA**, is immutable, and big, like a model data, so the service just need to request once and store as a member data for components use.

But the question is, the http get is async, I cann't guarantee the **DATA**'s construction is over when angular service's constructor finished, or when **DATA** needs to be used in any component's **ngInit()**.

How to deal with that? If use lazy load move http.get into every component's **ngInit()** function, the 3 pages is opened with random order, I have to check whether **DATA** is constructed in all 3 component, I think it's stupid.

Comment: http://learnangular2.com/es6/promises

Comment: Use `resolve` in your routes so that your components are activated after your datas are resolved: https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/10/10/resolving-route-data-in-angular-2.html

Comment: Resolve is a good solution, but if you want to stick with the service approach please post the service code and the way you subscribe to it in the component.